# Update current song name AVPLayer Xcode

Tags: iphone, avplayer

I would like to update current song name into this picture. I don't know how to call that one and need to show image. I am using AVPlayer now. I would like to know how to do.

[image]

I have tried this but it show error.

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:"_MPMediaItemPropertyTitle", referenced from:    -[PlayViewController playPressed] in PlayViewController.o**

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter]; 
infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"my title", MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                                           @"my artist", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                                           nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` in this class?

Is the MediaPlayer framework linked to your project?